# MySQL many-to-many schema setup

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm setting up a mysql db with posts and tags that looks like this:

```
posts    
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
[...]

tags
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tag   | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

post_tag_map
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| post_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| tag_id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The tags will be shared between multiple posts; 'red' may be used by post 5 and 10.

**My question is:** how do I prevent the deletion of a tag if it is being used by more than one post and delete it if it isn't?

**Note:** I am using Foreign Keys which I thought would take care of this issue but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
CREATE TABLE `post_tag_map` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`,`tag_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES posts(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES tag(`id`)
)
```

Comment: Do you need to add ON DELETE CASCADE somewhere in your foreign key?

Comment: @duffymo ON DELETE CASCADE would delete the tag if I deleted the map. I'm not sure that's what I want because if the tag is being used by another post I only want to delete the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete all tables in one go using a `delete` statement like this.

```
DELETE FROM post_tag_map, posts, tags
WHERE post.id = post_tag_map.post_id
AND tags.id = post_tag_map.tag_id
AND tags.id = 256;
```

However MySQL makes no guarantees about the order that the deletes will take place in.  If you have foreign keys, those may prevent the delete from taking place.

So either do not use `FOREIGN KEY` `**or** declare them with a`ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

Remember MyISAM does not support foreign keys, so there you only have the multitable delete.

More about multitable deletes here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to declare the foreign keys like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

the 'on delete cascade' is what will initiate the auto-delete. Note that the cascade will NOT propagate "up" the other side of the link table. If you delete a tag, only the matching records in post_tag_map will vanish, but leave the posts they were attached to alone.

Comment: @Marc this seems to be exactly what I want but it's not working. `delete from tags where id = 6;` doesn't delete the matching record. Also it doesn't prevent the tag 6 from being deleted since it is being used by more than one post.

Comment: You do need to be using InnoDB tables. MyISAM tables will ignore the foreign key definitions (they won't cause a syntax error, but they won't get honored either).

Comment: @Marc Thanks that has to be my issue

Comment: @Marc This may be another issue but now I'm getting :
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dp`.`posts_x_tags`, CONSTRAINT `post_x_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
 when I: `mysql> insert into post_x_tags(post_id, tag_id) values(1,1);`

Comment: You need a matching '1' record in both the tags and posts tables.

Comment: I do. `mysql> select id from posts; >  1 rows in set (0.00 sec)` 
`mysql> select id from tags; > 1 row in set (0.00 sec)` `insert into posts_x_tags values(1,1); ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fail`

Comment: do `show innodb status`. buried in the middle of all that output is a section that has "last foreign key error", which'll tell you exactly which table+field is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add to your FOREIGN KEY declarations:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Which declaration do you suggest? I've tried DELETE CASCADE but that doesn't seem to be what I want because if I delete a map it deletes the tag as well even if the tag is referenced by another post.